# Sshd root login errors even though root logins are disabled - how to solve?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, login, root

On my Linux server (Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS) I have set

```
PermitRootLogin no
```

in /etc/ssh/sshd_config
and reloaded the config with

```
sudo service sshd reload
```

But I am still seeing

```
Mar 14 06:18:02 myhost sshd[30049]: error: maximum authentication attempts exceeded for root from 11.222.111.22 port 16138 ssh2 [preauth]
Mar 14 06:18:02 myhost sshd[30049]: Disconnecting authenticating user root 11.222.111.22 port 16138: Too many authentication failures
```

in the logs. So how come? Should root logins be disabled completely? Why even ask for or check a password if root is not allowed?

Answer (score 1):

As you said you have disabled root login via `PermitRootLogin no`. By this, there is no possibility for root user to get login to your OS directly. In the logs you have mentioned, you see root logins because your server is probably published in the internet and robots are trying to login to your OS via root user.

My suggestion is to Disbale root login as you did, and add some Allowed users for example eng for engineers  or dev for developers or anyone to your sshd_config file as below.Thus you restrict the SSH login through these users.

```
AllowUsers eng dev tommy
```

For better/higher security, its good idea to change your port number from default 22 to something else,and if possible using public/private key authentication instead of password authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a `restart` rather than a `reload` as it's a bit more forceful.

Failing that, you could also try adding `DenyUser root` - it may be that `PermitRootLogin` still allows root to attempt to login, even though it would never be successful?

Comment: I am still getting the messages after **restart** - no difference here.
**DenyUser root** only adds another logline, stating that root is denied